# Iterate through ComponentModel List

Tags: templating, razormediator

I have a Razor Template where I need to order a list of component links by a particular field in descending order (Fields.Date). Normally when I want to loop through a list I would just do something like the below:

```
@foreach(dynamic item in Fields.Articles)
{
    //do something here
}
```

However the problem I am faced with is I need to sort the data before going into the loop and then write out the fields. Looking at the Razor Mediator documentation I can use List ComponentModel but I'm not sure what properties I can use?

```
@using Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Models;

@{
    List<ComponentModel> articleList = Fields.Articles;
}
```

I was hoping I would be able to do something like articleList.OrderByDescending(...).

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Did you already include System.Linq? That would give you OrderByDescending and other methods like that. If that didn't work for you, could you elaborate on the issue?

Comment: Thanks Peter, yes I have System.Linq I have tried adding articleList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Fields.Articles.Date) - can I do this considering Articles is a list of component links? I don't get any errors but to test if this works I need to write out my results. I assumed I could do this articleList.Title, articleList.Date, articleList.Body and so on?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't going to work, as you can't use lambda expressions over dynamic types.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming based on your code and comments that you are attempting to do something along the lines of:

(I modified the code a little to what the LINQ statement should look like, assuming that Fields.Articles is a list of Component Links, and each of those Components contains a field with Xml Name of "Date").

```
@using System.Linq;
@using Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Models;

@{
    List<ComponentModel> articleList = Fields.Articles;
    articleList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Fields.Date);
}

@foreach (var article in articleList) { ... }
```

The reason that you are not seeing any error and that the list is not sorting is because OrderByDescending returns a new sorted list... it doesn't alter the original list.  For your sample to work, you'd have to create one more list:

```
@{
    List<ComponentModel> articleList = Fields.Articles;
    var orderedList = articleList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Fields.Date);
}
```

You can then loop through your orderedList and it would be descending by date as expected.

A shorter version of the above using casting and creating less variables would be:

```
@{
    var articleList = ((List<ComponentModel>)Fields.Articles).OrderByDescending(x => x.Fields.Date);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work - I have had trouble in the past using extension methods from `System.Linq` in Razor templates, without using them as a static method of `Enumerable` as detailed in my answer.

Comment: Hi, do you remember the error or issue you were having? We currently do something very similar to what the OP is trying to do on my current project (sorting a bunch of articles on a page), as well as pretty extensive use of other LINQ statements.  The code in my code last block is almost identical to what we are using on one of our templates.

Comment: As I recall it was a simple `List has no method Take` on doing a `list.Take(int n)` after `@using System.Linq`. Doing `Enumerable.Take(list, n)` instead resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I seem to recall that the Razor Mediator has problems with extension methods. This means that, in order to use `OrderByDescending` and other Linq extensions, you'd have to do something like:

```
@ {
    using System.Linq;

    List<ComponentModel> articleList =
        Enumerable.OrderByDescending(Fields.Articles, x => x.FieldToSort).ToList();
}

@foreach(var article in articleList)
{
    <h2>@article.Fields.Title</h2>
    <p>@article.Fields.Summary</h2>
    ...
}
```